# Executing a Python script multiple times with different option flags

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I have a Python script using the `parser` package for setting option flags (like `-d dataset` and `-s size` etc. and finally the results are written to a file. How can i run the command many times (sequentially) with different option flags for each run?

I need something like this:

```
datasets = [a,b,c]
sizes = [100,200,300]

for dataset in dataset:                           #specify parameters
    for size in sizes:                            #specify more parameters
         python script.py -d dataset -s size      #run script
```

What would be the best (or even 'a') way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct translation of your pseudo/python-code to `bash`, with [arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) instead of `list`s  and [classic `for`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for) loops:

```
#!/bin/bash

datasets=('a' 'b' 'c')
sizes=(100 200 300)

for dataset in "${datasets[@]}"; do
    for size in "${sizes[@]}"; do
        python script.py -d "$dataset" -s "$size"
    done
done
```

If `sizes` are more like a `range`, and not a list of hand-picked values, you can use the [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace):

```
for size in {100..300..100}; do
    # ...
done
```

or the [arithmetic `for`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) loop:

```
for ((size=100; size<=300; size+=100)); do
    # ...
done
```